# Map a list of types with shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

```
case class Foo1(s: String) // Matching names

case class Foo2(s: String)
case class Bar(f: Foo2)

val foo = Foo1("foo") :: HNil
val fooGen1 = LabelledGeneric[Foo1]
val fooGen2 = LabelledGeneric[Foo2]
val barGen = Generic[Bar]

object mapping {
  implicit def caseFoo = at[Foo](f => fooGen2.from(fooGen1.to(f)))
}
val bar = barGen.from(foo.map(mapping))
bar == Bar(Foo2("foo"))
```

Is there a way to define `mapping` in a generic way? With a list of tuples of types.

Edit:

I have auto-generated case classes for the controllers and manually written case classes which contain the data I would like to put into the auto-generated case classes. The auto-generates ones look like

```
case class RequestanAccount200(result: CompaniesCompanyGetBody200ResponseBody)
  (implicit val writer: String => Option[Writeable[CompaniesCompanyGetBody200ResponseBody]])
  extends RequestanAccountType[CompaniesCompanyGetBody200ResponseBody] { val statusCode = 200 }

case class CompaniesCompanyGetBody200ResponseBody(company: Company)
case class Company(id: String, users: Users)
type Users = Seq[String]
```

and the manual case classes e.g.

```
case class ManualCompany(id: String, users: Seq[String])
```

From what I know, the implicits on the case class don't work too well with shapeless, so I figured I'd start generating at the `CompaniesCompanyGetBody200ResponseBody` level. I've got a `ManualCompany` and I would like a `CompaniesCompanyGetBody200ResponseBody`, preferably with the least boilerplate possible.

Comment: Can you say in words what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: I edited the post to add more information, I hope that clarifies it a bit.